# i beam cursor for windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

On Windows 10 Pro: Is it possible to change the underline `_` to an i beam cursor `|` in windows command prompt? I know this is possible on *nix but don't see anything in the Properties for Command Prompt.

Comment: https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/change-cursor-size-in-command-prompt-on-windows-10.html

Comment: That just makes the underline bigger, it doesn't make it an ibeam

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: On Windows 10 Pro @music2myear

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible within the default command prompt.

You can change the size and the color within the built-in Windows command prompt, but you cannot change the shape of the cursor.

Your only option is to choose a different console application that offers this feature.